# SDK location not found. CircleCi

Tags: android, circleci, fastlane

I am attempting to deploy a React Native Android application using CircleCI.

Here is the job

```
 android_deploy_staging:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/android:2021.12.2-node
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms512m -Xmx2g'
      GRADLE_OPTS: '-Xmx3g -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - *fetchDeployKeys
      - run: git config --global url."https://qadrebot:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
      - run: *set_node_version
      - restore_cache: *restore_npm_cache
      - run: *install_npm_dependencies
      - save_cache: *save_npm_cache
      - restore_cache:
          key: 4-gems-{{ checksum "android/Gemfile.lock" }}
      - run: cd android; bundle check || bundle install --path vendor/bundle --clean
      - save_cache:
          key: 4-gems-{{ checksum "android/Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
      - run:
          name: Install Fastlane
          command: sudo gem install fastlane
      - run:
          name: bundle install
          command: cd android && bundle install
      - run:
          environment:
            ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: '/home/circleci/android-sdk'
          name: Prepare environment and compile beta
          no_output_timeout: 30m
          command: |
            echo Executing fastlane
            yarn deploy_staging:android
```

However I get an error about the SDK location not being found.

```
[12:36:31]: -------------------
[12:36:31]: --- Step: clean ---
[12:36:31]: -------------------
[12:36:31]: $ /home/circleci/project/android/gradlew clean -p .
[12:36:31]: ▸ Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4-all.zip
[12:36:32]: ▸ .............10%..............20%..............30%..............40%..............50%..............60%..............70%..............80%..............90%.............100%
[12:36:34]: ▸ Welcome to Gradle 6.4!
[12:36:34]: ▸ Here are the highlights of this release:
[12:36:34]: ▸ - Support for building, testing and running Java Modules
[12:36:34]: ▸ - Precompiled script plugins for Groovy DSL
[12:36:34]: ▸ - Single dependency lock file per project
[12:36:34]: ▸ For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/release-notes.html
[12:36:35]: ▸ Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[12:36:49]: ▸ > Configure project :app
[12:36:49]: ▸ Reading env from: ./app/services/config/.env.staging
[12:36:49]: ▸ WARNING: DSL element 'DexOptions.incremental' is obsolete.
[12:36:49]: ▸ It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[12:36:49]: ▸ WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[12:36:49]: ▸ It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[12:36:49]: ▸ For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[12:36:51]: ▸ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[12:36:51]: ▸ * What went wrong:
[12:36:51]: ▸ A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
[12:36:51]: ▸ > Could not create task ':app:lintDebug'.
[12:36:51]: ▸ > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/circleci/project/android/local.properties'.
[12:36:51]: ▸ * Try:
[12:36:51]: ▸ Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[12:36:51]: ▸ * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[12:36:51]: ▸ BUILD FAILED in 20s
```

On the CircleCi website it states

> This image contains the Android SDK and CLI tools.

But it looks like maybe the Android SDK isn't installed?

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [cimg-android docker template code](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/cimg-android/blob/main/Dockerfile.template).

```
# Install Android SDK Tools
ENV ANDROID_HOME "/home/circleci/android-sdk"
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT $ANDROID_HOME
```

You don't need to set $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT yourself.

Instead, the sdk path can be refered with `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Answer (score 1):

```
      - run:
        name: 'Build Android App'
        command: |            
          export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='/home/circleci/android-sdk'
          export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64'
          npm run build:android
```